# web scraping without getting blocked selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy, ip

I am scraping this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2014-2015/results/ but sometimes the browser dont load the page or website cant be reached.
How could i fix this problem ?

```
home = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2014-2015/results/'
driver.get(home)

for i in range(1):
    scroll = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)

l=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='in-match']")

urls=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    urls.append(l[i].get_attribute('href'))



for i in urls:
    driver.get(i)
    sleep(5)
    date=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'match-date'))).text
    hometeam=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[1]/figure/div/a/img'))).get_attribute("alt")
    awayteam=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[3]/figure/div/a/img'))).get_attribute("alt")
    ft=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'js-score'))).text
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocked? is the page not loading because it is blocked?

Comment: The site is not loading however the script had error because it cant find data to scrape

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar question regarding extracting data from https://www.betexplorer.com,
but it has been deleted

the question looks like this

""Web Scraping a list of elements
I would scrape Matches, Date and Result row by row to csv file""

here is the code

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league/results/'
site = 'https://www.betexplorer.com'

getr = requests.get(url)
src = html.fromstring(getr.content)

game = src.xpath("//td[@class='h-text-left']//a//@href")
ft = src.xpath("//td[@class='h-text-center']//a//text()")
date = src.xpath("//td[@class='h-text-right h-text-no-wrap']//text()")

games = list()
fts = list()
dates = list()

for (gm, ftt, dat) in zip(game, ft, date):
    gm = site + gm
    getg = requests.get(gm)
    srr = html.fromstring(getg.content)
    teams = srr.xpath('//span[@class="list-breadcrumb__item__in"]//text()')
    for team in teams:
        games.append(team)
        fts.append(ftt)
        dates.append(dat)
        fullfile = pd.DataFrame({'Games': games, 'Fts': fts, 'Dates': dates})
        writer = ExcelWriter('D:\\yourpath\\games.xlsx')
        fullfile.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        writer.save()
```